Does a particle undergoing perfectly elastic collisions within a rectangle repeat its paths?
The problem is: given a rectangle, a point mass is placed at any point on the sides of the rectangle. For all time t≥0, the point mass moves inside the rectangle, undergoing elastic collisions upon hitting the edges of the rectangle. At time t=0, the point mass is launched from its initial position at an angle. What relationship must the length of the rectangle, the width of the rectangle, the launch angle, and the initial position of the point mass satisfy for the trajectory of the point mass to be periodic?
This is a problem I thought of while watching the logo thing bounces around on the screensaver when an older computer goes into standby.
I have tried three methods to varying degrees of success. If you'd like to know about them, read onward.
The first one is by transforming the problem into one where the point mass goes in a straight line. So let's construct a Cartesian coordinate system; place one given rectangle in the plane so that its length and width overlap with the axes and one of its tips overlaps with the origin; then, tile rectangles congruent to the given one throughout the plane. The point mass would be launched from either the length or the width adjacent to the origin. The problem then becomes that of discussing when will the straight line that results from this launch intersects some rectangle later at the same position in that rectangle as in the one from which it was launched. I have given this method the least thoughts because I think that it would be hard to generalize into a problem where the point mass bounces in shapes that cannot tile an Euclidean plane.
The second one is where we don't bounce a point mass in the rectangle: rather, we assume that many rays of light are emitted, at the same angle, from every point in some given line segment that is a subset of the length or the width of the rectangle. We then observe how the length of the line segment changes as light is reflected in the rectangle (Here the "line segment" is defined as the connected set of points where light is reflected from the length/width of the rectangle). According to my intuition, the limit of the length of those line segments after an infinite number of iterations should somehow be related to whether the path of the point mass would repeat. But this method suffers from the same problem as the next, which is that sometimes the point mass is bounced off the side adjacent to where it was launched, and sometimes it is bounced off the opposite side. To account for this is incredibly painful and non-enlightening.
The third one is where we consider the sequence of shapes formed by the line segment that is the path of the mass in between two consecutive bounces and the line segments that are subsets of the sides of the rectangles and that are also, let's say, always to the right of the motion of the mass. We then consider whether (and more importantly how) this sequence becomes cyclic.
This is basically a summary of my progress on this problem. Any hint, solution, or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

From the first viewpoint it is clear that whether a line intersects two rectangles in the rectangular grid in the same point, is invariant under affine transformations. So without loss of generality we may restrict our attention to the unit square.
The first viewpoint also shows that whether or not a line intersects the two squares in the same point, is invariant under translations of that line. So without loss of generality we may assume that the line passes through the origin.
Now the question reduces to which lines through the origin pass through a point with integer coordinates, other than the origin. These are of course precisely the lines with rational slope.
Translating this back to the original problem; the point mass returns to its original position whenever the slope is a rational multiple of the aspect ratio of the rectangle. It is independent of its starting position.


Another possible approach is to suppose that we have a discrete set of possible bounce locations (indexed by $s_{i}$ in the above figure), and departure angles (indicated by $\theta_{i}$).  These will map to the rectangular coordinate system shown in the lower part of the figure.
Now, at each bounce event $i$, there are three possibilities:
(1)  The index $s_{i}$ has never been encountered before, so we will obtain a new point at coordinate $\left(s_{i},\theta_{i}\right).$
(2)  The index $s_{i}$ has been encountered before, but at a different $\theta.$  We thus obtain a new point at coordinate $\left(s_{i},\theta_{i}\right).$
(3)  The index $s_{i}$ and angle $\theta_{i}$ has been encountered before.  This means that the path is now a complete cycle.
By the pigeonhole principle, the worst case period will be $n_{s} \times n_{\theta}$ number of bounces, where $n_{s}$ is the size of $\left\{s_{1}, s_{2}, \ldots, s_{n_{s}}\right\}$ and $n_{\theta}$ is the size of $\left\{\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}, \ldots, \theta_{n_{\theta}}\right\}.$

You assume that you have a discrete set of possible bounce locations and departure angles. But this assumption does not hold in general.
